# Missing register.json after clean install of gitlab ci

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I just installed `gitlab ci` on an `CentOS 6.5` machine and I started to add some projects.
The dashboard of `gitlab-ci` shows my `gitlab` project, but when I click the `add` button, nothing happens.

Looking at the `production.log` for `gitlab_ci`, I see every 5 seconds the message :

> Started `POST "/api/v1/builds/register.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-28 11:32:31 +0100`

Looking at the `gitlab_ci_access.log` log for `apache`, I see :

> `172.16.15.13 - - [28/Mar/2014:11:33:06 +0100] "POST /api/v1/builds/register.json HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "-"`

The DocumentRoot for `gitlab-ci` in the `vhost` file is `/home/gitlab/gitlab-ci/public`, but looking at this location, there is indeed no `api` directory.

So... I wonder at what point the api-directory would have been installed ?

Installation was done, following the directives on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) and adapting it where needed to my CentOS box.